# can't implement Matrix transitives in C++ ?

Tags: math, c++14, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to calculate the  Transitive of a matrix but this function does not calculate it right. 
any hint?

```
for (int k = 0; k < elements; k++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < elements; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < elements; col++)
        {
            Matrix[row][col] = Matrix[row][col] || (Matrix[row][k] && Matrix[k][col]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And *not right* means what exactly?

Comment: it means  it doesn't calculate the transitive of  a matrix right

Comment: Seriously? Please provide an example with input, output, and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that by *transitive* of a matrix you mean the *transpose* of a matrix. Create a new matrix object, and do something like:

```
for(int row = 0; row < elements; row++)
    for(int col = 0; col < elements; col++)
        NewMatrix[row][col] = Matrix[col][row];
```